# SwiftUI - Adjust ScrollView scroll indicator insets

Tags: swift, swiftui, scrollview

I am creating a chat app and I want the content of the ScrollView to go beneath the input field (while scrolling up). I already put the ScrollView and the input field in a ZStack. Bottom padding on the ScrollView puts the content up, but I also want the scroll indicator to move up with the content.

Is there any way to change the insets of the scroll indicator to match the padding, or any other workaround to achieve what I'm looking for?

Here's the current code:

```
          ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ScrollView {
                ScrollViewReader { value in
                    VStack(spacing: 5) {
                        ForEach(MOCK_MESSAGES) {
                            mMessage in
                            MessageView(mMessage: mMessage)
                        }
                        .onAppear {
                            value.scrollTo(MOCK_MESSAGES.count - 1)
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 40)
                }
            }
            MessageInputView(messageText: $messageText)
        }
```

Summing up: The idea is to have the ScrollView to be above the input view, but move the content underneath input view when scrolling up.

Comment: Please upload the code that you have tried so far

Comment: @LucaSfragara, uploaded.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @sheldor I answered with a couple of solutions

Answer (score 10):

**iOS 15 / Swift 3**

You could do this with `.safeAreaInset` instead of padding, then it handles the scroll indicator insets for you as well.

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { value in
        VStack(spacing: 5) {
            // stuff
        }
    }
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
    MessageInputView(messageText: $messageText)
}
```

Note: `.safeAreaInsets` doesn't seem to be working on `List` as of Xcode 13.1.

**UPDATE: As of iOS 15.2, `safeAreaInsets()` works with List and Form as well.**

**iOS 14 / Swift 2 or with List**

Like many things in SwiftUI, there doesn't seem to be a to do it without tinkering with the underlying UIKit components. There's an easy solution for this one though, using the [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) library:

```
ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
    ScrollView {
        ScrollViewReader { value in
            VStack(spacing: 5) {
                // stuff
            }
            .padding(.top, 10)
            .padding(.bottom, 40)
        }
    }
    .introspectScrollView { sv in
        sv.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.top = 10
        sv.verticalScrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 40
    }
    MessageInputView(messageText: $messageText)
}
```

You could also do it with a `List` with `introspectTableView`.

Comment: Hey @Steve M I do the same but I faced one issue. For example: we have a MessageInputView with dynamic height and when height is increased the ScrollView doesn't scroll up to keep the same content area visible. Do you know to fix/solve this issue? Thanks